# RabbitMQ Spring AMQP - Message Processing after some time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Using Spring AMQP (Using RabbitMQ as message broker), I am preparing a message and I want my message to consume after sometimes. Till then it can wait in some queue like **waiting queue** and then moved to our **main queue** where we have the consumer which is waiting to process the message from **main queue**.

I got confused whether I should apply dead letter exchange in this scenario and how to apply the dead letter exchange in it is the **big question for me**.

Any Idea how can we make it work.

P.S > If it is possible without rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange plugins.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the delayed exchange plugin, you can send a message to a queue with a time to live (ttl set on the queue or message).

Configure the queue to route expired messages to a dead letter exchange which routes to the final queue.

```
someExchange -> ttlQueueWithDLX -> DLX -> liveQueue
```